# nlog failing on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, file-permissions, nlog, error-logging

I have setup my asp.Net Core 5 application with Nlog for logging errors on LIVE environment. It has been working smoothly till recently when I realized that the hosting company reconfigured permissions to folders on the server, denying write permissions to some folders.
I started noticing that I was no longer able to upload files to some of the folders I had under www folder in the application.

When I brought their attention to it, they enabled write access to that folder and since then, I can upload files but I also noticed that at about the same time, my error logging stopped working. Locally, my error logging still works but not working on the production server anymore.

Now I wish to find out whether the error logging can be affected by the review of write permissions and how I might be able to troubleshoot the issue further and probably make some reasonable suggestions to the technical support team to help resolve the issue faster.

My Nlog configuration file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  autoReload="true"
  internalLogLevel="Info"
  internalLogFile="c:\temp\internal-nlog.txt">

 <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
 <extensions>
  <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore" />
  <add assembly="NLog.MailKit" />
  </extensions>

 <!-- the targets to write to -->
 <targets>
 <!-- write logs to file  -->
 <target xsi:type="File" name="alllogs" fileName="./logs/all-logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />

<!-- another file log, only own logs. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
<target xsi:type="File" name="errorlogs" fileName="./logs/error-logs/${shortdate}.log"
        layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />

<!-- Database Logging target -->
<target name="db" xsi:type="Database"
        dbHost="hosteserver"
        dbDatabase="databasename"
        dbUserName="username"
        dbPassword="password">
 
  <commandText>
    insert into dbo.ErrorLogs (
    Logtime, Level, Message, Exception,
    Logger
    ) values (
    @TimeLogged, @Level, @Message, @Exception,
    @Logger
    );
  </commandText>
  <parameter name="@TimeLogged" layout="${longdate}" />
  <parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
  <parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
  <parameter name="@Exception" layout="${exception:tostring}" />
  <parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
</target>

<!-- my mailkit target for email notifications on error -->
<target xsi:type="Mail"
     name="ErrorMailLogTarget"        
     subject="Error Occurred on The Application Name"
     to="myname@myemail.com"
    
     from="email@mydomain.com"
     body="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}"
     smtpUserName="email@mydomain.com"
      smtpServer="mydomain.com"
      smtpPort="587"
     timeout="20000"         
     smtpPassword="email_password"
     smtpAuthentication="basic"
     skipCertificateValidation="true"
     priority="Urgent"
   />
 </targets>

 <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
 <rules>
  <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
  <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="alllogs" />

<!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
<logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />

<!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="errorlogs" />

<!-- Error Mail notification log -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="ErrorMailLogTarget" />

<!-- Database Logging Provision -->
<logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="db" />
 </rules>
 </nlog>
```

I will appreciate any guide to resolve this.

Thank you

Comment: check if your server have access to the log database and respective port. could be a firewall blockage.

Comment: @MehrdadDowlatabadi the database is just one of the log options. I made provision for logging to file and also to email and none of these works at present but they all work when I serve the application from my local machine in development. Moreover, the database is available to the application though

Comment: Enable and check the [internal log](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-logging). It should give you a proper error message.

Comment: @Julian could you please give me a guide on how to go about that?

Comment: It's described in the link. If there is something unclear, please post a specific question on GitHub then.